# Variable not declared but have already been declared

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

I tried to declare a variable on a script, but it kept saying that the variable hasn't been declared. This is the code

```
<head>
    <style> 
        html,body {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
        }
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300;400&display=swap');
            body{
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            }

            .header{
                background-color: #Dcd517;
                padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
                font-size: 16px;
                text-align: center;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                margin:0px;
            }
            
            .header h1{
                padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
            }
            .header a{
                color: black;
                padding:20px;
                text-align: center;
                width: auto;
                border-radius: 12px;
                font-size: 32px;
                text-decoration:none;
            }

            .header a:hover{
                background-color:#9d940e
            }

            .cnt1{
                display: flex;
                background-color:#127D0B;
                padding: 8px 50px 8px 50px;
            }
            .items{
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                padding: 8px 8px 0px 8px;
            }

            .items a{
            background-color: #1105dc;
            color: white;
            padding:12px;
            mrgin: 8px;
            text-align: center;
            width: auto;
            border-radius: 12px;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-decoration:none;
            }

            .items img{
                background-color: white;
                margin: 8px;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = header>
        <a href="/"> <b> Pot.Io </b></a>
        <a href="/shop"> <b> Shop </b></a>
        <a href="/shop"> <b> Help </b></a>
    </div>
    <script lang="ts">

        let items = [
            {
                name: "test"
            },
        ];
       </script>

    <div class = cnt1>
    {#each items as item}
        <div class = item>
            <h1>{item.name}</h1>
        </div> 
    {/each}
    </div>
</body>
```

Error code:
Cannot find name 'items'. Did you mean 'item'?
'items' is not defined. Consider adding a  block with 'export let items' to declare a prop

I tried changing the variable, it did not work. I tried copying it from my previous project. It did not work.

Comment: Could you please remove unnecessary code from the snippet ? (eg. the CSS stylings) So the code may be more readable. See also: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `script` is within a body tag, thus it will behave like any regular `script` element. It has to be at the top level, to become the component's script which can declare variables to be referenced in the markup.

Generally you should not construct a full document in a Svelte component, you can however add things to the `head` via `<svelte:head>`. You also generally would not add styles directly to the `head` and just use a top-level `style` element, which scopes the styles to the component.

So the structure of a component usually is the following (order up to preference):

```html
<script>
  // props, state & code
</script>

<!-- markup here -->

<style>
  /* component styles */
</style>
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you, solved the problem.